# How to move <h:message> outside form?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, message

I have a form and I want to verify if the email already exists in database. I use this code:

```
<h:panelGroup id="messagePanel" layout="block">
  <h:messages errorStyle="color: red" infoStyle="color: green" layout="table"/>
</h:panelGroup>
<h:form>
  <h:panelGrid columns="2" class="form">
     <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateAdUserLabel_email}" for="email" />

     <h:inputText id="email" value="#{adUserController.selected.email}" 
                   title="#{bundle.EditAdUserTitle_email}" >
          <f:validator validatorId="emailVerification" />
          <f:ajax event="keydown" render="m_email" />
     </h:inputText>
     <h:message id="m_email" for="email" />
</h:form>
```

But I want to display the error message in the #messagePanel. I've tried to move the `#m_email` to the top but it doesn't recognize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the message panel inside the form.

```
<h:form>
 <h:panelGroup id="messagePanel" layout="block">
    <h:messages errorStyle="color: red" infoStyle="color: green" layout="table"/>
 </h:panelGroup>
 <h:panelGrid columns="2" class="form">
 <h:outputLabel value="#{bundle.CreateAdUserLabel_email}" for="email" />

 <h:inputText id="email" value="#{adUserController.selected.email}" 
               title="#{bundle.EditAdUserTitle_email}" >
      <f:validator validatorId="emailVerification" />
      <f:ajax event="keydown" render="m_email" />
 </h:inputText>
 <h:message id="m_email" for="email" />
</h:form>
```

Comment: it works for me and it displays in #m_email , how can i change it to display in #messagePanel.

Comment: it's because your `f:ajax` is set to update m_email: `<f:ajax event="keydown" render="m_email" />` change it to `@form` or `messagePanel`